# A cmake error about ros catkin in windows system

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake

my CMakeLists.txt is like belows,

```
...

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        rosbag
        sensor_msgs
        pcl_conversions
        nav_msgs)

...
```

During try to build code with ‘Cmake ..', following errors comes out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:.../build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from catkin.environment_cache import generate_environment_script
ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/noetic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(C:/Python27/python.exe
  "D:.../build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/opt/ros/noetic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:208 (safe_execute_process)
  C:/opt/ros/noetic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:21 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)
```

Comment: You are using Python 2.7 but [Noetic only supports Python 3+](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Migration). Did you follow [these steps](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) for your setup? Did you source ROS Noetic before executing any command? Did you verify that the `catkin` command is working (this invokes `CMake`)?

Comment: Hi, I just reinstalled ROS following the  steps on Windows and remove Python2.7, roscore can work on ROS shorcut which created in step 6.  How to source ROS Noetic ? I just copy C:/opt/ros/noetic/x64/setup.bat into ROS shortcut and press enter.  For verifying the catkin command, I only can create folder in C drive, and catkin can work well。

Comment: That what you did in step 6 is sourcing ROS, in other words the ROS commands incl. `catkin` can be used within this command window. You can move to any folder/disk and execute the ROS commands as long as you stay in this command window with the specific ROS environment setup through the `setup.bat`.